# How to convert string to Date without changing the GMT timezone

Tags: typescript, date, timezone

I have such string: let stringDate = `Thu Jan 21 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500`

i want to change it to the Date type, if using like this `new Date(stringDate);` this returns

```
Sat Feb 20 2021 05:59:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

how can i convert it correctly ? the expected output should be like `Thu Jan 21 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500` but in type `date`.

Comment: Wich language do you use? Typescript or Javascript?

Comment: I use typescript

Answer (score 0):

use helper function `convertTZ`

```
function convertTZ(date: Date, tzString: string) {
    const diff = date.getTime() -  new Date(date.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: tzString })).getTime()
    return new Date(date.getTime() + diff);
}
```

you can use such

```
let stringDate = "Thu Jan 21 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500"
const date = new Date(stringDate)
let dateIndiana = convertTZ(date, "America/Indiana/Indianapolis") //for GMT-0500 you can change it as you want

console.log(dateIndiana)
// Date: Date: "2021-01-21T12:00:00.000Z" 
console.log(typeof dateIndiana)
// "object"
```

Comment: for let `dateIndiana = convertTZ(date, "America/New_York")`
returns 
`"Thu Jan 21 2021 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)" `
what i need is for `let stringDate = "Thu Jan 21 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100"`
returns 
`"Thu Jan 21 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500"`

Comment: @Catalina see here  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJygFQFoAUAJgIZToBciAImegDSJQBeAylJjGAOZUDOHLtwCUiAN4BYAFCJZyBAMREYwYIgC8SugDpu6XDAC26AqIC0ssOgDuNOsR1Q4AGTgQSAG3TtOPAgCJ0MDMAVVZ-RjEmI3Q8BEomNkEeRABfYWFdfRwY02k5REx9EEwkK1tacgdyLINjU0QAaiUVYGEAbmlU6S8oRAFfbkr0DUR-HAALEEQAKRIkACYARkQFgAZlxDW1im3dtcQAcQBZHDM1gFZt-2kUMEVSclHyuyqBoWHhHv0tcgBJMDKeYkUZ3DDYfDVBhjACCxk47gA9AA5GwAfQAmnBMABrfyiRGI4DYo6nc5XA4ATzg03cSAgE3mekQMD6JD4iGp02s8yg0luCjgXm0Hjg3ChAKBYBIXykhNeCWGVH862W5yWZmWOCWC32+202zWeH8iAF9yF6BFYoIUEpAAd0HA1I90JKYMDZfL-HAAEYAK3Q0BuUmkQA

Comment: the output is `Thu Jan 21 2021 06:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`
what i need is `Thu Jan 21 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500`

Comment: @Catalina This is the output only when you do ``toString``
If you want a string by the position you need to use ``tolocalString``

Comment: Hi.  The approach used here is called "epoch shifting", as it adjusts the intent of the `0` timestamp by the offset.  While useful in some cases, the key point with epoch shifting is that you *don't* then pass that timestamp back to something that expects the original epoch.  In this case, constructing the `Date` object at the last line of `convertTZ` is in error because the `Date` object always uses an epoch of exactly `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: Also - there's no guarantee that the strings you're parsing will be supported.  Neither the input string format given here, nor that produced by `toLocaleString` follow the [ECMAScript Date Time String Format](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) - thus the parsing will be implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not possible with a `Date` object.  The `Date` object is internally based on *one single value* that is a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (given by `.getTime()` or `.valueOf()` or coercing to a number with `+`, etc.).  Such timestamps are specifically UTC based (think GMT+0).

When you use any of the non-UTC based functions of the `Date` object (such as `.toString()` and many others), the *local* time zone is applied during the function call.  It is not stored within the `Date` object itself, and thus cannot be changed.

The newer `Intl` based functions like `toLocaleString` can apply other time zones during their operation, supplied via the `timeZone` option.  But this results in a `string`, not a `Date`.  Any attempt to put it *back* into a `Date` object will be problematic as one would be interpreting the local time from one time zone as if it were the local time of another.  (This can lead to failures near DST transitions.)

These problems (and many others) are being worked on for the JavaScript language via the [ECMAScript TC39 Temporal Proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html).  In the meantime, you can use a library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) *instead* of a `Date` object.